# Kentico UI site Login using Username Instead of Email

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-api

In the kentico UI site, they have a login form, in which there are two textboxes (email and password). Users access the site login using email. Now I need to access using UserName instead of Email. In the CMS_User table UserName column, the values are there. How do I edit my code?

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on how the user is created. If the user is created with a username that is am email address then it stores that email address in the username as well as the users email field. So in this case there is no reason to switch the code to use the other field.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, maybe provide some more info.